# Regex is also preventing new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some confusion in Regex so I need help.my question is I am using the following Regex to prevent string should not start with some character and should not contain angular bracket.this regex also preventing next line as well so can u help me to modify it according to my need.

```
^(?![@=+*-])(?!.*[<>]).*$
```

Thanks
working example-->https://regex101.com/r/5GZQl7/1

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Perhaps a few test cases?

Comment: @Vivek check Sweeper's answer it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that `.` does not match line endings, so as soon as you put a new line in there, the regex does not match.

Ideally, we want it to match *everything*, including line endings. What syntax can match everything? One way to do this is to use complementing character sets. `\s` matches all the whitespace, `\S` matches all the non-whitespace, so `[\s\S]` will match everything!

Replace all your `.`s with `[\s\S]`!

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5GZQl7/2)